# xarray.Dataset: Change value of coordinates while keeping attributes?

Tags: python-xarray

I have an xarray.Datastruct with coordinates with attributes *long_name*, *unit* and *range*. I want to change the values of one of the coordinates (let's call it coordA), but keep the attributes.

I've tried my_struct.assign_coords(coordA = new_values), which do change the values but also removes all attributes from coordA.

Comment: Please — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it by giving coords in its tuple format.

```
my_struct=my_struct.assign_coords({'coordA':('coordA',new_values,my_struct.coordA.attrs)})
```